# Ruta runs fine in a uimaFIT pipeline, but no output using workbench in project built from Maven archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, uima, ruta

I have generated a UIMA Ruta project using the maven archetype as described in [Section 4.4 of the documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.archetype). In addition, I have added to Maven the necessary imports to perform my usual UIMA tasks. Following Peter's answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404738/how-to-create-pipeline-of-java-nlp-and-ruta-scripts),  I am able to run this basic test script:

```
PACKAGE NLP;
DECLARE Animal;
"dog|cat" -> Animal;
```

using a UIMA fit pipeline as follows:

```
CollectionReaderDescription cr = createReaderDescription(
            TextReader.class,
            TextReader.PARAM_SOURCE_LOCATION, "F:/rutasample/",
            TextReader.PARAM_PATTERNS, new String[] { "[+]*" },
            TextReader.PARAM_LANGUAGE, "en");

    AnalysisEngineDescription ruta = createEngineDescription(RutaEngine.class, 
            RutaEngine.PARAM_SCRIPT_PATHS, "C:/Users/mdeangelis/workspace/nlp-ruta/src/main/ruta/NLP/",
            RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "test3");
    AnalysisEngineDescription writer= createEngineDescription(XMIWriter.class, 
                XMIWriter.PARAM_OUTPUT, "test/output");

    runPipeline(cr,ruta,writer);
```

This runs with no errors and generates the output as expected.

I am now trying to get the Ruta workbench running so that I can test Ruta scripts using the excellent features provided. I know that my project does not follow the recommended folder layout in the documentation, but since it is generated from the Maven archetype (and I have updated the paths in the pom.xml file) I assume that is okay. The path update included adding buildPaths:

```
script:src/main/ruta/ 
descriptor:target/generated-sources/ruta/descriptor
resources:src/main/resources
```

What I am trying now: I have the above Ruta code in a file called test3.ruta and I have an input folder (with a single .txt file) and output folder directly below the project main directory. The input folder contains a single document. I run my Ruta file as "UIMA Ruta", but nothing happens. I don't get an error, I just get a blank console and no output in the output folder. Running the same Ruta code in the ExampleProject provided on the Ruta website runs as expected, so I assume that it has something to do with my configuration.

Any ideas on what the problem might be, or how I can get a more descriptive error message?

Comment: I assume that the documents has soem file extension like `txt`? Can you check if the generated descriptor for the script is valid and that is located at the expected location?

Comment: Which path did you update in the pom.xml? buildPath script/descriptor?

Comment: Yes, the input file is a .txt. I set <analysisEngineOutputDirectory> to "target/generated-sources/ruta/descriptor" and the descriptor is there, under the NLP package, as "test3RutaAnnotator.xml". It appears to be valid, since it contains the "Animal" annotation (which I did not add myself, although the pipeline run might have).

I updated any paths that seemed necessary in the pom.xml, including adding buildPaths:

    script:src/main/ruta/
    descriptor:(same path as above)
    resources:src/main/resources

Comment: Which version of UIMA Ruta do you use? ruta-core maven dependency and the installed Ruta Workbench?

Comment: You could test the generated analysis engine description directly in the Java code above in case there is a problem with the descriptor. Normally, the descriptor is not found at all when nothing happens. However, all seems to be correct. In newer ruta versions, e.g., 2.6.0, there should be a (more) descriptive error message in the console.

Comment: I am using 2.6.0 for both the Workbench and ruta-core.

Following your suggestion, I ran the Java code directly on the descriptor and got a disambiguation error (there's an "Animal" type in DKPro too). I fixed that in the script above (`"dog|cat" -> NLP.test3.Animal;`) and the descriptor runs successfully in Java, but still nothing running the same script as UIMA Ruta. I'll keep playing with it.

Is there another place that the output might be, or a setting in Maven that changes it? Perhaps I changed it inadvertently?

Comment: The output folder can be configured in the launch configuration. I'll try to reproduce the problem next week.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: I just created a new project using the archetype and added the script buildpath. The launcher works here as expected. Can you try it with a clean archetype project? Have you tested using the the descriptor in java?