# NLP Pipeline, DKPro, Ruta - Missing Descriptor Error

Tags: uima, ruta, dkpro-core

I am trying to run a RUTA script with an analysis pipeline.

I add my script to the pipeline like so `createEngineDescription(RutaEngine.class, RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "mypath/myScript.ruta)`

My ruta script file contains this:

```
IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos
    FROM desc.type.POS AS pos;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Lemma
    FROM desc.type.LexicalUnits;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token
    FROM desc.type.LexicalUnits_customized AS token;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.dependency.Dependency
    FROM desc.type.Dependency AS dep;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.type.ReadabilityScore
    FROM desc.type.ReadabilityScore;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata.type.TagsetDescription
    FROM desc.type.metadata;

UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpSegmenter;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpPosTagger;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.corenlp.CoreNlpLemmatizer;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.maltparser.MaltParser;
UIMAFIT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.readability.ReadabilityAnnotator;

uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-CONTAINS(pos.POS)} -> {
    uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-> SETFEATURE("language", "en")};
EXEC(OpenNlpSegmenter);
EXEC(OpenNlpPosTagger);  
EXEC(CoreNlpLemmatizer);
EXEC(MaltParser); 
EXEC(ReadabilityAnnotator);
};
```

This generates the error -> Annotation exception: Initialization of annotator class "org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine" failed.
(Descriptor: unknown)

Do I need a descriptor?   This answer [How to create pipeline of java nlp and ruta scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404738/how-to-create-pipeline-of-java-nlp-and-ruta-scripts) suggests to me that its not required but perhaps I am misunderstanding what is required.  If it is needed then how do I add it?

I am using uimafit-core:2.5.+ and org.apache.uima:ruta-core:2.8.1

Scanning for other solutions I also tried this

```
AnalysisEngine aae = createEngine(RutaEngine.class,
            RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "myscript.ruta",
            RutaEngine.PARAM_SCRIPT_PATHS, new String[] { "src/main/resources/ruta" },
            RutaEngine.PARAM_ADDITIONAL_EXTENSIONS, new String[] {
                    BooleanOperationsExtension.class.getName(),
                    StringOperationsExtension.class.getName()});
```

but with no improvement.  I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.  This error was being thrown simply because the script could not be found and I had to change this line from:
RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "myscript.ruta"
to:
RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "myscript"

However, I did a few other things before this that may have contributed to the solution so I am listing them here:

1. I added the ruta nature to my eclipse project
2. I moved the myscript from resources to a script package